# Сохранение переменной типа List в DTO с помощью JPQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, dto

Здравствуйте, для получения информации с базы данных использую `Spring Data`. И возник такой вопрос:
Допустим есть `ентити` с полем типа `List<"Тип объекта">`. Знаю, что с помощью `JPQL` можно сохранить данные сразу в ДТО. Но можно ли сохранить этот самый `List<"...">` в ДТО?

Comment: Если ответ помог - не забывай его отметить/принять...

Answer (score 0):

Это называется [Проекции](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). Сначала описываешь проекцию (т.е. ДТО):

```
public PersonProjection {

    @Value("#{target.name}") 
    String getName();

    @Value("#{target.addresses}")
    List<Address> getAddresses();
}
```

(Начиная со Spring Boot версии 1.5.9 аннотации '@Value' не обязательны. До версии 1.5.9 - присутствовала [ошибка](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1173?focusedCommentId=153855&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-153855), из-за которой List'ы не формировались.)

Затем ее можно использовать в методе репозитория, например так:

```
Optional<PesronProjection> findByPesronId(Long id);
```

Здесь Spring Data JPA извлечет объект Person из базы по его ID, и создаст ДТО объект PersonProjection с полями 'name' списком адресов 'addresses'.

Аналогично можно сделать кастомный запрос:

```
@Query("select p.name as name, p.addresses as addresses from Person p where p.id = ?1")
Optional<PesronProjection> findByPesronId(Long id);
```

Здесь обязательно нужно применять алиасы (`as name`, `as addresses`), чтобы система знала чем заполнить проекцию.